# Domain alias - Multi-Boutique Prestashop - Plesk

Tags: dns, prestashop, plesk

I want to be able to install a Prestashop in multi-shop mode on a dedicated Plesk server, with two aliases of different domains.

The first (shop.domain1.fr) would be the host of prestahsop, but I do not see at all how to connect the second domain alias (shop.domain2.fr) to the hosting of the first.

Do you have any links or tracks i could use ?

Thank you !

Comment: i changed it  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must park second domain or sub-domain in first one. It means that both of them must have same DocumentRoot. When you create a subdomain, change DocumnetRoot to shop folder.

See **crate a subdomain** section in this link:

https://www.pickaweb.co.uk/kb/create-addon-sub-parked-with-plesk/